# react doesn't fetch api properties when state changes, but fetches when re-renders?

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this error

> img.user.username undefined.

```
<Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.user.username}</Typography>
```

When uploading images

```
  handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        // console.log(this.state.description)
        // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            const newImage = {...response.data}


            //update component-state
            this.setState({
                image_url: newImage.img_url,
                description: '',
                images: [
                   {
                      id: newImage.id,
                    //   user: newImage.user.username,
                      image_title: newImage.image_title,
                      img_url: newImage.img_url,
                      created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
                      updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
                   },
                    ...this.state.images,

                ],

            })

        });
    }
```

`{...response.data}` does not contain the property `user` so this error is understandable, however when i refresh the page

`img.user.username` **shows the username .** and their is no error.

this fetches the posts from the back end, how can i make it work both ways, like when a image is uploaded as well as when it refreshes the page.

*If their is a better way to edit the question title, please make a better question title.*

```
componentWillMount(){
    Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
        // let img;
        // let imgTitle;
        Object.keys(response.data).forEach( (key) => {
            console.log(response.data[key]);
            this.setState({
                images:[ ...this.state.images, response.data[key]]
            })
            console.log(this.state.images);
        });
    })
}
```

**full code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import ImageUploader from 'react-images-upload';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Axios from '../Axios';
import Image from './Image';
import moment from 'moment';
class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            image_url: 'http://www.conservewildlifenj.org/images/artmax_1001.jpg', 
            images: [], 
            description:'',
            upload:false,
        }
    }
    handleUpload =  file =>  {
        const data = new FormData()
        const image = file[0]
        // console.log(this.state.description)
        // data.append('ourImage', this.state.description)
        data.append('ourImage',image, this.state.description )
        Axios.post('/images/upload', data).then((response) => {
            const newImage = {...response.data}


            //update component-state
            this.setState({
                image_url: newImage.img_url,
                description: '',
                images: [
                   {
                      id: newImage.id,
                    //   user: newImage.user.username,
                      image_title: newImage.image_title,
                      img_url: newImage.img_url,
                      created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
                      updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
                   },
                    ...this.state.images,

                ],

            })

        });
    }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
        // console.log(this.state.description)
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        Axios.get('/images/uploads').then( (response) => {
            // let img;
            // let imgTitle;
            Object.keys(response.data).forEach( (key) => {
                console.log(response.data[key]);
                this.setState({
                    images:[ ...this.state.images, response.data[key]]
                })
                console.log(this.state.images);
            });
        })
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.images.length !== prevState.images.length) {
            console.log(this.state.images);
        }
        // debugger;
    }
    onUploadClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            upload: !this.state.upload
        })
    }
    deleteImg = (id) => {
        Axios.post(`/images/delete/${id}`).then( () => {
           this.setState({
               images: [ ...this.state.images.filter(img => img.id !== id)]
           })
        })
    }
    render(){
        const uploader = ( 
            <ImageUploader
                withIcon={true}
                withPreview={true}
                onChange={this.handleUpload}
                singleImage={true}
                buttonText='Upload an image'
                imgExtension={['.jpg', '.gif', '.png', '.gif']}
                maxFileSize={5242880}
            />
        )
        return(
            <div>
            <Grid container justify="center" spacing={16}>
                <Grid item sm={8} md={6} style={{ margin: '40px 0px', padding: '0px 30px'}}>
                    <Typography align="center" variant="h6">
                        Welcome to the Dashboard
                    </Typography>
                        <Button onClick={this.onUploadClick} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                            {/* toggle between Upload or Close
                                Will be upload by default, else if upload is clicked, close will show.
                            */}
                            {!this.state.upload ? "Upload": "Close"}

                        </Button>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        {this.state.upload ? (
                            <div>
                             <TextField
                                 id="outlined-name"
                                 label="Image Title"
                                 name="description"
                                 type="text"
                                 required={true}
                                 fullWidth
                                 style={{ borderRadius: '0px'}}
                                 className=""
                                 value={this.state.description}
                                 onChange={this.handleChange}
                                 margin="normal"
                               />
                                <br></br>
                                <br></br>
                                {/* so here what we are saying, if this text field is FILLED show the uploader component 
                                else hide it.
                                */}
                                {this.state.description ? uploader : null}

                            </div>
                        ):(
                            null
                        )}
                    {this.state.images.length > 0 ? (
                        this.state.images.map( (img, i) => (     
                            <Grid item sm={12} md={12} key={i} style={{ margin: '30px 0px'}}>
                                    <Paper style={{padding:'20px 20px'}}>
                                        {/* // empty image_title */}
                                        <Typography style={{ padding: '30px 5px', letterSpacing:'8px', textTransform:'uppercase'}} variant="h4" align="center">{img.image_title}</Typography> 
                                        <Divider style={{ width: '150px', margin:'10px auto', backgroundColor:'#000000'}} variant="middle" />
                                    <Image image_url={img.img_url} />   
                                    <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{img.user.username}</Typography> 
                                    <Typography variant="h6" align="center">{moment(img.created_at).calendar()}</Typography> 
                                    <Button onClick={() => this.deleteImg(img.id)} variant="outlined" component="span" color="primary">
                                        Delete
                                    </Button>
                                </Paper>                              
                            </Grid>
                        ))
                    ) : (
                        <div>
                            <Grid item md={8}>
                                <Typography>No Images yet</Typography>
                            </Grid>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Grid>
                {/* Images  */}
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Dashboard;
```

**backend**

```
router.get('/uploads', async (req, res) =>  {
    await Image.query( (image) => {
        image.orderBy('img_url', 'DESC')
        image.limit(10)
        // if you want to include the user with the image, you would use the withRelated 
    }).fetchAll({withRelated: ['user']}).then( (images) => {
        // console.log(images.toJSON());
        return res.status(200).json(images.toJSON());
    })
})

router.post('/upload',  multipartMiddleware,  upload.single('ourImage'), (req, res) => {
     if(!req.files){
         return res.status(500).send("Please upload a file");
     }
    //  console.log(req.files)
    cloud.uploader.upload(req.files.ourImage.path, {crop: "fill", folder: '/uploads'} ,    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        // console.log(req.user)
        const img = new Image({
            img_url:result.url,
            image_title:req.files.ourImage.name,
            user_id: req.user.id

        });
        // console.log(img);

        img.save().then( img => {
            return res.status(200).json(img);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your actual problem is that your backend methods GET `/images/uploads` and POST `/images/upload` does not have the same properties for each item, i.e. `user` is not provided in response of POST `/images/update`, leading to inconsistency of data in frontend.

Best solution: ensure response data is the same for both by adding `user` to your response of POST `images/upload`

If you cannot do so:

- One solution is to refresh the whole list once image is uploaded, i.e. calling `Axios.get('/images/uploads')` again. This is costly, but ensure all items in your data has required properties for rendering.
- Another solution is to skip showing the username for the uploaded image:

```
<Typography variant="h6" align="center">{!!img.user ? img.user.username : ""}</Typography>
```

This will not keep integrity of your list, though.

- Another cheap solution is assigning current username as `user` for newly uploaded image if you store it somewhere in React app, since the uploader will always be current user.

```
this.setState({
                image_url: newImage.img_url,
                description: '',
                images: [
                   {
                      id: newImage.id,
                    //   user: newImage.user.username,
                      image_title: newImage.image_title,
                      img_url: newImage.img_url,
                      created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
                      updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
                      user: {
                        username: currentUser.username // add this if you store it somewhere
                      }    
                   },
                    ...this.state.images,

                ],

            })
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the back-end POST response is returning your data in the same format as the GET response.

```
const img = new Image({
  img_url:result.url,
  image_title:req.files.ourImage.name,
  user_id: req.user.id
});

Image.save().then(img => {
  /* Do something like this, but for a single image...
  await Image.query(image => {
    image.orderBy("img_url", "DESC");
    image.limit(10);
  })
    .fetchAll({ withRelated: ["user"] })
    .then(images => {
      return res.status(200).json(images);
    });
  */
});
```

Also, when you call setState in the handleUpload method, you are not setting a `user.username` property on the new object you are appending to the images array. Maybe try replacing

```
this.setState({
  images: [
    {
      id: newImage.id,
      //   user: newImage.user.username,
      image_title: newImage.image_title,
      img_url: newImage.img_url,
      created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
      updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
    },
    ...this.state.images
  ]
})
```

with

```
this.setState({
  images: [
    {
      id: newImage.id,
      user: {
        username: newImage.user.username
      },
      image_title: newImage.image_title,
      img_url: newImage.img_url,
      created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
      updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
    },
    ...this.state.images
  ]
})
```

or to simplify it even further

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  images: [
    {
      ...newImage,
      created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
      updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
    },
    ...prevState.images
  ]
}))
```

Comment: the problem with querying the images in the post method, is that its a post method, and i would need to use `GET` method to query the images when the post method is executed, you know what i mean ?

Comment: i added this to my backend  post method      `img.save().then( async () => {
            await Image.query(image => {
                image.orderBy("img_url", "DESC");
                image.limit(10);
              })
                .fetchAll({ withRelated: ["user"] })
                .then(images => {
                  return res.status(200).json(images);
                });
              
        });`

Comment: i think i have a solution .

Answer (score 0):

So after getting feedback from @blaz and @Gabor Szekely I refactored the code, and now it works.

I realized that I needed to use `[0]` when it came to making the post request and then showing the post when its uploaded. like this

```
this.setState({
    description:'',   // resets title after upload
    images: [
        {
        id: newImage[0].id,
        user:{
            username: newImage[0].user.username
        },

        image_title: newImage[0].image_title,
        img_url: newImage[0].img_url,
        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', ''),
        updated_at: new Date().toLocaleString().replace(',', '')
        },
        ...this.state.images
    ]
})
```

As well as querying the images, within the `POST` method. I was under the impression that I would not be able get images inside a post request, but you certainly can. As well as make your route to `router.post` to `router.all`.

However, I wanted to keep it as post because it works either way.

```
router.post('/upload',  multipartMiddleware,  upload.single('ourImage'), (req, res) => {
     if(!req.files){
         return res.status(500).send("Please upload a file");
     }
    //  console.log(req.files)
    cloud.uploader.upload(req.files.ourImage.path, {crop: "fill", folder: '/uploads'} ,    (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        // console.log(req.user)
        const img = new Image({
            img_url:result.url,
            image_title:req.files.ourImage.name,
            user_id: req.user.id

        });
        // console.log(img);
        // fetches image with user when a upload is made
        img.save().then( async () => {
            await Image.query(image => {
                image.orderBy("img_url", "DESC");
                image.limit(10);
              })
                .fetchAll({ withRelated: ["user"] })
                .then(images => {
                  return res.status(200).json(images);
                });

        });

    });
});
```